# CLI pointers to unmanaged C++ code

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper, command-line-interface

I'm working on my first C++/CLI wrapper and am getting very confused wrt pointers. In the particular project I've got, I'm attempting to wrap an unmanaged C++ dll so I can use it in a C# app. Two objectives here: (1) to be able to use the library in my app, and (2) to learn to do this. Many hours of searching on this site and Google have yielded a bunch of answers that come close; I just can't seem to get all the way there. The unmanaged library I'm trying to incorporate is the key-value store "LevelDB" (I know of at least one .NET wrapper out there but, like I said, I'm trying to learn this).

The code below is the beginning of a CLI wrapper class *written as if in unmanaged code.* I.e. this, functionally, is what I'm trying to accomplish. Not surprisingly, this generates the following compiler error:

```
cannot convert parameter 3 from 'cli::interior_ptr<Type>' to 'leveldb::DB **'
```

When I began, I naively thought that I could/should replace the DB* pointer with a pinned pointer, something like

```
pin_ptr<leveldb::DB*> db
```

but this yields a similar error and doesn't work. Other combinations with interior pointers and handles (which, if I understand right, are not applicable here because the library is unmanaged) haven't worked either. I'd appreciate any advice pointing me in the right direction. Any references to good posts/articles would be great too but please include a word or two on how to adapt for my case since, after reading tons of them, I seem to be no closer. Thanks!

Example wrapping class:

```
#pragma once
#include "leveldb/db.h"

using namespace System;

namespace Wrapper
{
    public ref class DBWrapper 
    {
        leveldb::DB* db;

    public:
        DBWrapper()
        {
            leveldb::Options options;
            options.create_if_missing = true;
            leveldb::Status status = leveldb::DB::Open(options, "/tmp/testdb", &db);
        }

        ~DBWrapper() 
        {
            delete db;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Maybe inside a `ref class`, `T*` doesn't mean "pointer to `T`"? Just a guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a local variable:

```
DBWrapper()
{
    leveldb::Options options;
    options.create_if_missing = true;

    leveldb::DB* local_db(nullptr);
    leveldb::Status status =leveldb::DB::Open(options, "/tmp/testdb", &local_db);
    db = local_db;
}
```

The object under construction (pointed to by `this`) can be moved by the garbage collector, so a member variable does not have a fixed address.

Comment: Yes. I'm in a world of linker problems now but this answers my question. Obvious in retrospect. Thank you.